# Input field is always evaluated in child component

Tags: angular

I have an input field `gradingKeys` which I pass data from the parent component.

That works only when there is data passed but I use the component at different places where initially there is no `gradingKeys` Array.

```
export class GradingKeyComponent {

  groupedGradingKeys: any[];
  @Input() set gradingKeys(gradingKeys: any[]) {
    if (gradingKeys) {
     let query = // do stuff

      this.groupedGradingKeys = query;
    }
  }
}
```

I thought when I use a setter I can better control the input evaluation of the child component, because I used the `ngOnChanges` event before where I got the same error.

I do NOT want to check whether `gradingKeys` is truth-y... Also that would work!

What angular 2 approach should I try then in my scenario?

**ERROR**

```
error_handler.js:45EXCEPTION: Error in ./TestsCreateComponent class TestsCreateComponent - inline template:131:20 caused by: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefinedErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:45
error_handler.js:47ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefinedErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47
error_handler.js:50ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50
error_handler.js:51TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
    at EnumerableImpl.[Symbol.iterator] (linq.js:122)
    at EnumerableImpl.Select [as _factory] (generators.js:27)
    at Select.next (<anonymous>)
    at Object.getKeyedMap (utilities.js:47)
    at EnumerableImpl.GroupBy (linq.js:422)
    at GradingKeyComponent.set [as gradingKeys] (grading-key.component.ts:19)
    at _View_TestsCreateComponent1.detectChangesInternal (TestsCreateComponent.ngfactory.js:788)
    at _View_TestsCreateComponent1.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:272)
    at _View_TestsCreateComponent1.DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:377)
    at _View_TestsCreateComponent0.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (view.js:290)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:51
error_handler.js:54ERROR CONTEXT:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
error_handler.js:55DebugContextErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:55
Subscriber.js:227Uncaught ViewWrappedError
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You reference "where I got the same error" but I don't see any actual error listed.

Comment: Its updated with the error I got!

Comment: And you're iterating over the gradekeys in the template? Either an *ngIf guard or an Elvis operator (?) on the for. Alternatively initialize to an empty array.

That's my guess, anyway.

Comment: As I wrote when I check for gradingKeys is truthy... then there is no harm... using Elvis is the same. I do not want to use guards. I want to know what angular2 approach is better, if there is none ok then I go the elvis rock my world way!!!

Comment: There isn't a better one, the expected behavior is that it explodes when that is undefined because there's no guard ensuring it exists.